# Can I use Flex Layout with Angular and .NetCore

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-flex-layout

I am building a test app with Angular and .Net Core 3. However, when I install Flexlayout and run my app I get a "Cannot GET /". I tried installing Flexlayout in a brand new project and I got the same error. It Flexlayout even compatible with .NetCore?

Comment: The [angular flexlayout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) is purely an NPM package, so installing it into your angular project should not directly affect the ASP.NET Core build. Can you run `ng build` from your angular project directory and post the results? Also if some errors pop up in the Visual Studio `Output` Window, post them here

Comment: This is for a brand new project.
First I run this npm install --save @angular/flex-layout @angular/cdk in cmd, in the angular directory of my app. I add the import in the app.module.ts. And then I build the project. The ng build command and the Output in VS show the same thing - https://pastebin.com/9U4qCN0Y . When the browser opens I see "Cannot GET/".

Comment: The issue appears when I add import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout'; in the app.module.ts file and add FlexLayoutModule  in the imports section. When I remove it the project runs as expected.

Comment: After I install Flexlayout I see that there is a message - found 277 vulnerabilities (269 low, 1 moderate, 7 high) run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details. So I ran  the npm audit fix command and when I run the project I see this - https://pastebin.com/E0QquH9e . So that didn't help as well :)

Comment: I'll take a look at it

Comment: Any progress???

Answer (score 0):

So, after a week of dealing with this ****ing issue I finally resolved it. The reasons for the error are :

1. installed angular cli on my machine was the newest(10), while in the project VS2019(Angular build template) is using 8.2.1.

2.the flex layout was also the newest version

3. the angular cdk was 10

So I uninstalled my angular cli globally and installed version 8.2.1. I installed version 8.2.1 of the cdk and flex layout as well. And now I don't get the error when I run the project. AT least for now :D :D :D